# Bioisosteric replacement using SMARTS (KNIME and RDKit)

Tags: computational-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

I am trying to create a KNIME workflow that would accept a list of compounds and carry out **bioisosteric replacements** (we will use the following *example* here: *carboxylic acid to tetrazole*) automatically.

> NOTE: I am using the following workflow as inspiration : [RDKit-bioisosteres (myexperiment.org)](https://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/2683.html). This uses a text file as SMARTS input. **I cannot seem to replicate the SMARTS format used here.**

For this, I plan to use the [Rdkit One Component Reaction](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.onecomponentreaction2.RDKitOneComponentReactionNodeFactory) node which uses a set of compounds to carry out the reaction on as input and a SMARTS string that defines the reaction.

**My issue is the generation of a working SMARTS string describing the reaction.**

I would like to input two SDF files (or another format, not particularly attached to SDF): one with the group to replace (*carboxylic acid*) and one with the list of possible bioisosteric replacements (*tetrazole*). I would then combine these two in KNIME and generate a SMARTS string for the reaction to then be used in the *Rdkit One Component Reaction* node.

> NOTE: The input SDF files have the structures written with an
> attachment point (*COOH for the carboxylic acid for example) which
> defines where the group to replace is attached. I suspect this is the
> cause of many of the issues I am experiencing.

So far, I can easily generate the reactions in RXN format using the [Reaction Builder node](https://nodepit.com/node/com.epam.indigo.knime.rbuilder.IndigoReactionBuilderNodeFactory) from the Indigo node package. However, converting this reaction into a SMARTS string that is accepted by the [Rdkit One Component Reaction](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.onecomponentreaction2.RDKitOneComponentReactionNodeFactory) node has proven tricky.

What I have tried so far:

1. Converting RXN to SMARTS ([Molecule Type Cast](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.chem.base.node.converter.parser.MolParserNodeFactory) node) : gives the following error code : `scanner: BufferScanner::read() error`
2. Converting the Source and Target molecules into SMARTS (*Molecule Type Cast* node) : gives the following error code : `SMILES loader: unrecognised lowercase symbol: y`

   - showing this as a string in KNIME shows that the conversion is not carried out and the string is of SDF format : `*filename*.sdf 0 0 0 0  0 0    0 V3000M V30 BEGIN` etc.
3. Converting the Source and Target molecules into RDkit first ([RDkit from Molecule](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.molecule2rdkit.Molecule2RDKitConverterNodeFactory) node) then from RDkit into SMARTS ([RDkit to Molecule](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.rdkit2molecule.RDKit2MoleculeConverterNodeFactory) node, SMARTS option). This outputs the following SMARTS strings:

   - Carboxylic acid : `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]`
   - Tetrazole : `[#6]1:[#7H]:[#7]:[#7]:[#7]:1`

This is as close as I've managed to get. I can then join these two smarts strings with `>>` in between (output: `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]>>[#6]1:[#7H]:[#7]:[#7]:[#7]:1`) to create a SMARTS reaction string but this is not accepted as an input for the Rdkit One Component Reaction node.

> Error message in KNIME console :
> ERROR RDKit One Component Reaction 0:40       Creation of Reaction from SMARTS value failed: null
> WARN  RDKit One Component Reaction 0:40       Invalid Reaction SMARTS: missing

Note that the SMARTS strings that this last option (3.) generates are very different than the ones used in the [myexperiments.org example](https://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/2683.html) (`[*:1][C:2]([OH])=O>>[*:1][C:2]1=NNN=N1`). I also seem to have lost the attachment point information through these conversions which are likely to cause issues in the rest of the workflow.

**Therefore I am looking for a way to generate the SMARTS strings used in the myexperiments.org example on my own sets of substituents.** Obviously doing this by hand is not an option. I would also like this workflow to use only the open-source nodes available in KNIME and not proprietary nodes (Schrodinger etc.).

Hopefully, someone can help me out with this. If you need my current workflow I am happy to upload that with the source files if required.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Stay safe and healthy!

-Antoine

Comment: For ChemSE's community -- it is my hunch only -- this might be a bit too special.  But addressing this question to RDKit's user group mailing list (https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/, free subscription) with what you did and what you aim for may well yield an answer in less time and more detail than here.

Comment: Another possibility is [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com) SE, though I admit I don't know how much expertise there is different chemical notations in this community.